# How do I align button to the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get 2 button in the middle of my screen. However these buttons are overlapping with the code that I have now. I actually don't use that much CSS, so this is probably a newbie question.

This is my html:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:20px;
  color: white; 
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.button1:hover{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button button1">button</button>
  <button class="button button1">button2</button>
</div>
```

I have no idea on how to align these buttons to the middle and leave a little space in between the buttons. If someone can help  me, I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: Is there any specific reason to add `absolute` position in `.button`?

Comment: I did that because then it went in the middle but now these 2 overlap. If i remove the absolute position, the button gets under the particles-js div

Comment: Can you add screen short of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using `text-align: center` to horizontally center nested elements

You can achieve this by declaring `text-align: center` on the containing parent element (`.wrapper`) and declaring `display: inline-block` on nested children elements.

`position: absolute` must be removed since we want to **keep** elements in the natural *document flow* - in order for this method to work, elements must be either `static` or positioned `relative`.

**Note:** for horizontal alignment, using `text-align: center` to work as expected, a few requirements should be met:

1. The containing parent element must be a *block* element (e.g:
   `display: block`)
2. The nested elements you need centered should be *inline-block*
   elements (e.g: `display: inline-block`)
3. No `float` rules should be declared on the nested elements you are
   intending to horizontally align, `float` rules will negate any effort
   to align elements in this way

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* always useful when working with border or padding properties, or any other property that can effect the box-model */
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray; /* so we can actually see what's happening */
  padding: 20px; /* Give us some breathing room */
}

.button {
  display: inline-block; /* naturally creates "whitespace" between inline elements */
}

.button1 {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:20px;
  color: white; 
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  /* non-essential augmentations */
  transition: .7s; /* smooth out the state change on pseudo-state :hover */
  min-width: 100px;
}

.button1.with-margin {
  margin: auto 10px; /* for additional spacing between inline elements*/
}

.button1:hover{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button button1">button</button>
  <button class="button button1">button2</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button button1 with-margin">button</button>
  <button class="button button1 with-margin">button2</button>
</div>
```

Or... you could *Just use Flex*...

#### Using `flex-box` to horizontally center nested elements

By declaring `display: flex` on the containing parent element (`.wrapper`), then `justify-content: center` to specify the horizontal alignment, you get the intended result. `flex-box` leverages the browser's built-in power to do all the "heavy lifting" and calculations for precision alignment - which, incidentally, also makes it a popular responsive solution.

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray; /* so we can actually see what's happening */
  padding: 20px; /* Give us some breathing room */
  /* Additional */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* always useful when working with border or padding properties, or any other property that can effect the box-model */
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray; /* so we can actually see what's happening */
  padding: 20px; /* Give us some breathing room */
  /* Additional */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block; /* naturally creates "whitespace" between inline elements */
}

.button1 {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:20px;
  color: white; 
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  /* non-essential augmentations */
  transition: .7s; /* smooth out the state change on pseudo-state :hover */
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: auto 10px; /* additional spacing between nested elements */
}

.button1:hover{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button button1">button</button>
  <button class="button button1">button2</button>
</div>
```

**Heads up!** `flex-box` has poor or limited support for legacy browsers, so if this is going to be a concern for you, it's probably better not to use it in production.

IE <= 9 - *Not Supported*
IE 10,11 - *Partial Support*
**See more:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

### Edit

#### Vertical & Horizontal Alignment using `flex-box` & `position: absolute`

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray; /* so we can actually see what's happening */
  padding: 20px; /* Give us some breathing room */
  /* Additional */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Further Additions */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* always useful when working with border or padding properties, or any other property that can effect the box-model */
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray; /* so we can actually see what's happening */
  padding: 20px; /* Give us some breathing room */
  /* Additional */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Further Additions */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block; /* naturally creates "whitespace" between inline elements */
}

.button1 {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:20px;
  color: white; 
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  /* non-essential augmentations */
  transition: .7s; /* smooth out the state change on pseudo-state :hover */
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: auto 10px; /* additional spacing between nested elements */
}

.button1:hover{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button button1">button</button>
  <button class="button button1">button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This already helped a bit, but now i would like to align these buttons to the middle of my screen. This is how is looks right now: https://gyazo.com/47ca5944136274fca206ccb6a1edb2c4

Comment: I used the answer above, however all this information will come in really handy and i will definitely take a good look at it, and you also gave me some nice layout and animation. Thanks you so much as well!

Comment: Happy to help, and glad you found this answer useful. There is a lot of information to digest here, but it'll make things easier for you moving forward for future situations where solutions such as these are required.

Comment: I just wanted to make a cool landing page for school, so I used Particles.js for the animated background. But these buttons didn't do what i wanted so i just had to ask. I'm really happy that it works now so I can code some Jquery again :)

Answer (score 4):

If you remove absolute position from button that it automatically center

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background:#ccc;
  padding: 20px;  
}

/*.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}*/

.button1 {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:20px;
  color: white; 
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.button1:hover{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button button1">button</button>
  <button class="button button1">button2</button>
</div>
```

Updated Answer using your screen short. For that just wrap the both div in one parent div and set position relative to it. and add position absolute in `.wrapper`.

```css
.hero-banner {
  background:#ccc;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white; 
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  margin:0 5px;
}

.button1:hover{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-banner">
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button button1">button</button>
    <button class="button button1">button2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work in the snippet, however it doesn't work in my code, it still gets below my "particles-js"  div. Any idea on how i can get it in there?

Comment: can please add screen short of it?

Comment: This worked, awesome and thanks you so much. I changed the height so it fills my screen again! thanks so much

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.button1 {

  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:20px;
  color: white; 
  border: 3px solid #fff;

}

.button1:hover{
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
</style>

<div id="particles-js"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button button1">button</button>
  <button class="button button1">button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That actually made my buttons exactly in the middle, but now it still overlaps. I must have done something real bad

Comment: try z-index if overlap issue

Comment: Where should i add that?

Answer (score 0):

```
.button {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%}
```

Comment: This also still overlaps the 2 buttons in my code... I really dont know what i did wrong