# Aligning buttons side by side by 3 using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been reading through the similar problems posted here by the others but none have manage to solve my problem although I have been trying the solutions suggested. So, I decide to ask he question. I have six buttons that represent six department and I want it to place two buttons side by side. Now I manage to do that, but the buttons doesn't want to get to the center of the page. This is my source code.

```js
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

```css
 body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  background-image: url("background.jpg ");

}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.btn {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: black;
  
 
 /* text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px #eee;
  border-radius: 30px;
 }

/* Demo Stuff End -> */

/* <- Magic Stuff Start */

.btn:hover {
  background-position: right center; /* change the direction of the change here */
}

.btn-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
}

.btn-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 51%, #fbc2eb 100%);
}

.btn-3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #84fab0 0%, #1aff1a 51%, #84fab0 100%);
}

.btn-4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a1c4fd 0%, #d147a3 51%, #a1c4fd 100%);
}

.btn-5 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffecd2 0%, #ff1a75 51%, #ffecd2 100%);
}

.btn-6 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-panel">

  <center>
<h1> Good Services Delivery</h1></center>
  <br />
  <br />
  <center>
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-1">Arrival & Emergency</a>
  <a class="btn btn-2">Obstetric & Gynecology</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-3">WAD</a>
  <a class="btn btn-4">Ortopedik & Medikal </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-5">Pediatrik</a>
  <a class="btn btn-6">Mortuary</a>
</div>
  </center>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is what my index.php look like right now
[image]

So, what should I do actually so that my buttons will be on the center?

Comment: try to read about text-align property of css

Comment: can u share a screenshot or image what do you wantt exactly?

Comment: I wish that the buttons will be on the center, like the Good Services Delivery

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to center anything using `text-align: center` if you are declaring `float` rules on your buttons. Also `center` tag has been deprecated in favour of using `text-align: center`, so don't use that - see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: You also have `flex-box` rules declared on `.container` but you are not using that as a containing parent element for your buttons.

Comment: Okay but your HTML structure of buttons not properly and you have used unwanted <div>, <br> and  <center> tags in that. Please check out your code carefully.

Comment: That's what I don't know how to change. I've tried several options but it doesn't work and I don't keep the codes I have used to show.

Comment: Helpful reference points for aligning anything *horizontally center* in css: https://jsfiddle.net/o4dzsc0k/1/ **&** https://jsfiddle.net/9guxnvwz/

Comment: Also, check out my JS fiddle. Thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/sayedrafeeq/pvkpdj90/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I align button to the middle of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054766/how-do-i-align-button-to-the-middle-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the **Flexbox** on the parent of the `.main-panel` which is the `body` element, to center it horizontally, get rid of the unneeded `br` tags as well as the deprecated `center` element, and apply `column-count: 3;` on the `.parent` div of the `a` tags.

```css
body {
  display: flex; /* added */
  justify-content: center; /* added */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("background.jpg ");
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
/* added */
.main-panel > h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-panel > .parent {
  column-count: 3;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-panel > .parent > a {
  display: block;
}
/****/
.btn {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* margin: 10px; */
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* added */
  padding: 30px;
  /* float: left; */
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: black;
  /* text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 #eee;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

/* Demo Stuff End -> */

/* <- Magic Stuff Start */

.btn:hover {
  background-position: right center; /* change the direction of the change here */
}

.btn-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
}

.btn-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 51%, #fbc2eb 100%);
}

.btn-3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #84fab0 0%, #1aff1a 51%, #84fab0 100%);
}

.btn-4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a1c4fd 0%, #d147a3 51%, #a1c4fd 100%);
}

.btn-5 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffecd2 0%, #ff1a75 51%, #ffecd2 100%);
}

.btn-6 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
}
/* added */
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .main-panel > .parent {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-panel">
  <h1> Good Services Delivery</h1>
  <div class="parent">
    <a class="btn btn-1">Arrival & Emergency</a>
    <a class="btn btn-2">Obstetric & Gynecology</a>
    <a class="btn btn-3">WAD</a>
    <a class="btn btn-4">Ortopedik & Medikal </a>
    <a class="btn btn-5">Pediatrik</a>
    <a class="btn btn-6">Mortuary</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is center tag is not supported in html 5. You can do this easily with boostrap.

complete code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
!-- language: lang-css -->

     body{
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      margin:0;
      background-image: url("background.jpg ");

    }
    .btn {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 30px;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: 0.2s;
      background-size: 200% auto;
      color: black;


     /* text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
      box-shadow: 0 0 0px #eee;
      border-radius: 30px;
     }

    /* Demo Stuff End -> */

    /* <- Magic Stuff Start */

    .btn:hover {
      background-position: right center; /* change the direction of the change here */
    }

    .btn-1 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
    }

    .btn-2 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 51%, #fbc2eb 100%);
    }

    .btn-3 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #84fab0 0%, #1aff1a 51%, #84fab0 100%);
    }

    .btn-4 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a1c4fd 0%, #d147a3 51%, #a1c4fd 100%);
    }

    .btn-5 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffecd2 0%, #ff1a75 51%, #ffecd2 100%);
    }

    .btn-6 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
    }  

    .main-panel{
        text-align: center;
    } 
</style>
</head>

<body>




<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->



    <div class="main-panel">

      <h1> Good Services Delivery</h1>

      <br /><br />

         <div class="container-fluid">
                             <div class="row col-md-offset-3">              
                             <a class="btn btn-1 col-md-4">Arrival & Emergency</a>
                             <a class="btn btn-2 col-md-4">Obstetric & Gynecology</a>
                             </div>

                             <div class="row col-md-offset-3">
                             <a class="btn btn-3 col-md-4">WAD</a>
                             <a class="btn btn-4 col-md-4">Ortopedik & Medikal </a>
                             </div>

                             <div class="row col-md-offset-3">
                             <a class="btn btn-5 col-md-4">Pediatrik</a>
                             <a class="btn btn-6 col-md-4">Mortuary</a>
                            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```